# Sa'eed Bin Mansur: A weak narrator in Sahih Muslim?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal

Salam Guys!

Sa'eed Bin Mansur can be found in Sahih Muslim 1350c, 2382b, 1252a, etc. He is also found in narrations that are present in other collections like Sunan Abu Dawud, Adab Al-Mufrad, Musnad Ahmad, etc. Since all the narrators of Sahih Muslim are Thiqa (Trustworthy), this suggests that Sa'eed Bin Mansur is also a trustworthy narrator. But why did Ad-Dhahabi declared him as weak in Mizan Al-Itidal? Here is an excerpt from Mizan Al-Itidal (See highlighted text in red):-

[image]

**This reads:-
وأما يعقوب الفسوى فقال : كان إذا رأى في خطابه خطأ لم يرجع عنه**

**Which means:-
As for Yaqub Al-Faswa, he has stated, "If he saw a mistake in his (Sa'eed Bin Mansur's) speech, he did not rectify it."**

**So if Sa'eed Bin Mansur made mistakes, then why is he considred thiqa (trustworthy) by Imam Muslim and why did Imam Muslim included his narrations in his Sahih collection?**

Thanks.

Comment: Who is Ya'aqub al-Fasawi compared to imam Ahmad and Abu Hathim? The statement doesn't necessarily has to be taken literally nor does it have any impact on his qualities as a narrator.

Comment: He is a narrator of all six books, including Bukhari. Where do you get the idea that Imam Dhahabi declared him weak? As it says in your screenshot right next to the name that he is thiqah. The statement of Yaqub Al-Faswa has been interpreted as praise not a criticism,  see https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1882&bk_no=60&flag=1

Comment: @UmH - I am not a native Arabic speaker. This was forwarded to me, so I decided to ask this question. What is the exact translation of Ya'aqub Al-Fasawi's statement that I highlighted?

Comment: Sa'id ibn Mansur is a known hadith scholar who has been entitled hafidh and author of a hadith compilation named after him "Sunan Sa'id ibn Mansur". Ya'aqub al-Fasawi is a known historian he studied hadith.